# How to add type definitions for includes in a Prisma model?

Tags: typescript, prisma

The example in the documentation looks like this:

```
const getUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: 1,
  },
  include: {
    posts: {
      select: {
        title: true,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

But when I want to read the property `getUser.posts` I get the following error:

```
TS2339: Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'User'.
```

Where can I find the correct type definitions the for the includes option?

Comment: What's your schema look like?

Comment: The docs for this are at https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The generated types do not include relations because queries don't return relations by default. To include the related models in your type, use the provided Prisma utility types like so:

```js
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

type UserWithPosts = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{
  include: { posts: true }
}>
```

Comment: We use several nested includes in our query so I'm fear it turns into a nightmare to write proper typed code. We then need to use `Prisma.PostGetPayload<{include: { subclass: true }}>` as a type for intermediary variables, so we declare several time the same relationship of payloads...

Comment: Thank you for this. Couldn't find anything at all about this in the documentation.